# Android: versionCode with cordova-plugin-app-version

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

i'm using the plugin cordova-plugin-app-version to get the versionCode and VersionNumber in my Hybrid Application on Android.

But there seems to be a problem with the versionCode. My AndroidManifest.xml looks like:

```
<manifest  android:versionCode="200420151420" android:versionName="0.0.1"
```

But my Android Tablet the versionCode displayed is a strange number like -1443311503

Does somebody have the same problem? Where does this come from? In my opinion it should be the timestamp from android:versionCode="200420151420" .

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `200420151420` is too big. The highest value you can use is `2147483647`

> **android:versionCode** — An integer value that represents the version of the application code, relative to other versions.

Reference:
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html

> **int**: By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -2^31 and a maximum
>   value of 2^31-1

Reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html